# Postgresql how to create a custom id column formatted with character, date and number

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

```
CREATE SEQUENCE customers_seq;
CREATE TABLE customers (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEXTVAL ('customers_seq'),custom_id VARCHAR(100),test varchar(10)
)
```

I need the sequence to go like so:

```
CU22_001
CU22_002
CU22_003
```

Explanation

CU - Is Stable Character

22 - Todays year date format (yy)

001 - Increments by +1 when a new value is added.

Next year (2023)..

the sequence needs to be reset back to 001 but the 20 changes to 21 because of the year being 2022 :

```
CU23_001
CU23_002
CU23_003
```

Question

How can I create this custom ID column BEFORE INSERT the new row?

Comment: I think `postgres 9.1` might not work as your expectations. Would you mind upgrading your Postgres version higher than 12?

Comment: my version is postgresql 14

Answer (score 3):

After Postgres version 12, we can try to use [Generated Columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html)

> The generation expression can only use immutable functions.

So that we need to create `generate_custom_id` immutable function which generate your expect `custom_id` format.

```
CREATE FUNCTION generate_custom_id(id INT)
returns text
as
$$
  SELECT 'CU' || TO_CHAR(now(), 'YY')|| '_' || TO_CHAR(id,'FM000');
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

then use that in your `custom_id` column

```
CREATE SEQUENCE customers_seq;
CREATE TABLE customers (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEXTVAL ('customers_seq'),
  custom_id VARCHAR(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( generate_custom_id(id)) STORED,
  test varchar(10)
);
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7df64d7113b740611f149e09a106c168)

Comment: I need when the year is changed the id will be reset 001

Comment: You requirement seems to be 'CU22_001 .... CU22_999 ...' and then CU23_001'? 
maybe reset the sequence when it arrives at 1000. 
But one question,  in one year,  the customer (new added ) count not more than 999 always?

Comment: it is not a trigger function